# How to flush all firewalld rules?

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I'm working on buidling a firewalld bash script to pre-configured some centOs7 servers and I cannot find any documentation talking about how to perform a full flush of firewall rules.

I'm looking for the equivalence in centOS6 with iptables :

```
flush(){
echo "Flush all chains"
iptables -F
iptables -X
}
```

Regarding that I'm not able to find an equivalence I'm think I may misunderstood something with firewalld..

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: You don't really do that with firewalld. It manages the firewall. You need to rethink your entire approach to whatever you're doing.

Comment: your bash script should restart the service to have the new settings take effect (remember that the user executing the script should have permissions to restart the service).  see http://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/how-to-startstop-or-enabledisable-firewalld-on-centos-7